# How to update few fields in JSON file and again read the JSON with updated values in selenium using Java

Tags: java, json, selenium

How to update few fields in JSON file and again read the JSON with updated values in selenium using Java.

Below is my JSON :
I want to update

```
{
"DemoFileJson": [
{
  "name": "demoPan",
  "Type": "patientcare",
  "indication": "fever",
  "disease": {
    "code": "282292002",
    "label": "Uncertain diagnosis"
  },

  "identified": false,

  "specimens": [
    {
      "name": "primarySpecimen",
      "type": {
        "code": "442524009",
        "label": "a.m. specimen"
      },
      "studyIdentifier": "Stud1",
      "studySubjectIdentifier": "Part1",
      "accessionNumber": "TSO500-MJ678",
      "dateAccessioned": "2019-03-29T20:00:00Z",
      "datecollected": "2019-03-29T20:00:00Z",
      "dateReceived": "2019-03-29T20:00:00Z"
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to deserialize the JSON?

Comment: Selenium is used to automate the browser. Is this JSON file being updated through the browser, or do you just need to manipulate this data in Java? I suspect this has nothing to do with Selenium.

Comment: Here  DemoFileJson is a json array and inside that there is another array "specimens" : and I want to update that array along with "accessionNumber" object at the same time in java.

Comment: @GregBurghardt : Yes, it's only for java.

Answer (score 0):

```
search & update value json file, with java class

example json file
[{"trx_id":"123"},{"trx_id":"123","datetime_expired":"20221102"}]

public class cariJSON {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
         JSONArray dd = updateJson("datetime_expired", "20331001");    
             try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C://file.json")) { //store data
            file.append(dd.toString());
            file.flush();
             }
            System.out.println(dd);
   }
    
    public static JSONArray updateJson(String keyString, String newValue) throws Exception {
            
      String jsons = readFileAsString("C://file.json");
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsons);  
      for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++)
      {
           JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(j).toString());
            // get the keys of json object
         
            if (obj.get("trx_id").equals("123"))
        {
            
            Iterator iterator = obj.keys();
            String key = null;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                key = (String) iterator.next();
                // if the key is a string, then update the value
                if ((obj.optJSONArray(key) == null) && (obj.optJSONObject(key) == null)) {
                    if ((key.equals(keyString))) {

                        obj.put(key, newValue);
                        jsonArray.remove(j);
                        return jsonArray.put(obj);                 
                    }

                }
                // if it's jsonobject
                if (obj.optJSONObject(key) != null) {
                    updateJson(keyString, newValue);
                }
                // if it's jsonarray
                if (obj.optJSONArray(key) != null) {
                    JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray(key);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        updateJson(keyString, newValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            System.out.println("Output array : " + jsonArray);
            return jsonArray;
           }
        return null;            
    }
}
```